# One-One relationship, delete.Cascade on way but delete.Restrict the other way

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Suppose I have the following entities.

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public int BlogImageId{ get; set; }
        public virtual BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogImage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

I want the following behaviour in the database:

1. Deleting a blog will also delete the BlogImage
2. Attempting to delete a BlogImage results in error (restrict it).

I am going in circles about this. I have managed to get the BlogImage deleted if a Blog is deleted, but then the restriction of deleting a BlogImage does not work (i.e. it allows me to delete it). And vice-versa. Basically, I can configure either (1) or (2), but not both at the same time.

The snippet below is the configuration that allows the BlogImage to be deleted if Blog is deleted. This works. But how can I do now so that BlogImage can not be deleted?

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasOne(x => x.BlogImage)
        .WithOne(x => x.Blog)
        .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(x => x.BlogId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```

The main reason why I want to do this (besides understanding ef core ofc), is that in my case, Blog represents a class with many properties. So instead of having all this properties, I partition it into (sub)types (=> composition). Hence, in my case, BlogImage is just a "helper" or part of a Blog, i.e. it does not make sense to just have a BlogImage by its own.

So I want a one to one relationship, with delete.Cascade one way, and delete.Restrict the other way.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, not possible.

It also goes against all conventions. It would mean that a dependent entity exerts some authority over the principal entity. (At least if I understood the question crrectly, I'm not sure!!)

You've clearly read the references:

[Microsoft docs: Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)

If it's not in there ... .

If I misunderstood the question, please let me know, I'll remove this answer consequently.

Comment: To be sure we understand each other: In my case, the Blog is the principal and the BlogImage is the dependent. If I delete the Blog, the BlogImage is deleted. So far so good. Now, if I allow the deletion of a BlogImage(i.e. while keeping the Blog), then the Blog would have a reference to a BlogImage that does not exist. This leaves the Blog in "bad state" . For example, attempting to delete the Blog after deleting the BlogImage will result on an error, since its trying to find the BlogImage that does not exist anymore. Isn't this an unwanted behaviour?

Comment: (1/?) No, the principal does not know about any specificity of a record in the dependent. In the Blog table, you will not find any reference to something in the dependent BlogImage-Table. Only in the BlogImage-table there's a reference to the principal, through the fk_column, an Id-record of the related Image. What happens when you delete a blogimage? You delete a line in the blogImage-table. Nothing happens in the Blog-table, because nothing needs to happen there. There's no record that could be impacted. Whether a blog has or does not has an image is irrelevant (and the table does "need

Comment: to know" in order to function). Are you trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist? Are you getting confused by the navigator-items? Only the Fk, the BlogId in the BlogImage-table, has a physical representation in the BlogImage-table.

Comment: If you want to prevent "orphaned" BlogImages, cascadeDelete, does that. If you want to prevent BlogImages from being deleted, that's not on the db-level. If you want to impose every Blog needs to have an image => ctor, not on the db-level.

Comment: But I also could be totally misunderstanding the question, if so, plz accept my sincere apologies.